# Getting Value Error for keras model when running in flask - Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, flask, image-processing, keras

I have a facial recognition model which works fine when an image is passed to it, whether as a seperate file, or a webcam capture. However, I moved it to a browser basd application and sent the webcam image to the server which is a python code running Flask.

I tested to see if the image is properly processed, ran `cv2.imread()`on it, which worked fine. But when I passed that image for the model prediction, I got this error:

> ValueError("Tensor %s is not an element of this graph." % obj)
>   ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_4/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 7),
>   dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

This wasn't happening otherwise, i.e when I ran the code as pure Python one (from the terminal, NOT as a browser application). This is the code:

```
@app.route('/image',methods=['POST'])
def image():
    json_file = open(f'{model_path}/fer.json', 'r')
    loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
    json_file.close()
    loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
    loaded_model.load_weights(f"{model_path}/fer.h5")
    i=request.files['image']
    f = ('%s.jpeg' % time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))
    i.save('%s/%s' % (path, f))
    full_size_image = cv2.imread(f"{path}/{f}")
    try:
        gray=cv2.cvtColor(full_size_image,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    except Exception as e:
        gray = full_size_image
    face = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
    faces = face.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3  , 10)
    artist,track=None,None
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        print("face detected")
        roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        cropped_img = np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(cv2.resize(roi_gray, (48, 48)), -1), 0)
        cv2.normalize(cropped_img, cropped_img, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_L2, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)   
        yhat= loaded_model.predict(cropped_img) #THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
        break
    return Response("%s saved"%f)
```

I've put a comment next to the line where the error occurs in the above code.

The function hasn't been changed at all, only the `@app.route` part is new

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: plz don't laugh but i got error then i figure out something which solved my error. When we load our model before executing app.run() we should use our model 4 or 5 time. like model = keras.load_model("something.h5") and use random image predict it 4 or 5 time then execute app.run()

Comment: I don't see how that would resolve this error???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix in [this](https://kobkrit.com/tensor-something-is-not-an-element-of-this-graph-error-in-keras-on-flask-web-server-4173a8fe15e1) which says that a Flask web request creates its own Tensorflow session , and not the default one, so you need to make it use the default session.

However this created another error along the lines of "Container location does not exist". The fix to this was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513905/not-found-container-localhost-does-not-exist-when-i-load-model-with-tensorflow), which combined with the solution from the first link, solved my problem